# How can you find a divisor of the numerator of 1-1/2+1/3-1/4-...+1/47

Tags: nt.number-theory

How can you find a divisor of the numerator of the sum:
 1-1/2+1/3-1/4-...+1/47

there are alternatives given such as 59, 61, 67, 71 and 79
using a calculator you get the answer is 71 but how can you do it without it?

Comment: The sequence of numerators is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A058313 where it says, "A Wolstenholme-like theorem: for prime $p > 3$, if $p = 6k-1$, then $p$ divides $a(4k-1)$...." For $k=12$, this says 71 divides the numerator of the sum out to $47$. But no link is given to a proof.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: if there are $n$ alternatives to choose from, then choose the $(n-1)$-st.

---

Long answer: the assertion in the comment of Gerry Myerson is easy to prove:
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{4k-1}\frac{(-1)^{j - 1}}{j} = \sum_{j = 1}^{4k - 1}\frac{1}{j} - 2 \sum_{j = 1}^{2k - 1}\frac{1}{2j} = \sum_{j = 2k}^{4k - 1}\frac{1}{j}.$$
Then just group the sums $\frac{1}{j} + \frac{1}{6k - 1 - j}$.

One could also rewrite the sum $\sum_{j = 1}^{4k}\frac{(-1)^{j - 1}}{j}$ as $\sum_{j = 2k + 1}^{4k}\frac{1}{j}$ and get a similar statement for $4k$ and $6k+1$.

Comment: Yes, the $4k,6k+1$ statement is also at the oeis link.

Comment: I understand the long answer but not the short one. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Vincent This belongs to the deep theory of psychology and statistics. For an example, see https://blog.prepscholar.com/most-common-answer-on-act (which is the first result I found with google).